# Magento 2 Add/Remove Extra info in API(carts/mine/items/) payload

Tags: magento2, rest-api, quote, cart-items

I'm trying to add product via API call

```
https://testdomain.com/rest/V1/carts/mine/items/
```

my payload is

```
{
  "cartItem": {
    "sku": "444375",
    "qty": 1,
    "product_option": {
      "extension_attributes": {
        "custom_options": [
            {   
                "option_id":"sqm_check_single",
                "option_value":"true"
            }
        ],
        "configurable_item_options": [],
        "bundle_options": []
      }
    },
    "quoteId": "5"
  }
}
```

and it returns the response

```
{
    "item_id": 63,
    "sku": "444375",
    "qty": 1,
    "name": "Place Product SAMPLE",
    "price": 2.3433,
    "product_type": "simple",
    "quote_id": "5",
    "product_option": {
        "extension_attributes": {
            "custom_options": [
                {
                    "option_id": "sqm_check_single",
                    "option_value": "true"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

My requirement is to remove the **custom_options** from response and add custom price to product on the basis of custom_options value I'm currently using **sales_quote_product_add_after** event but I'm unable to unset the custom_options from response. Is there any other way to set identification to payload about a product which we can fetch and use and it doesn't save .